# Why can I store a string in the memory address of a char?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, memory-address

I'm starting to understand pointers and how to dereference them etc. I've been practising with `int`s but I figured a `char` would behave similarly. Use the `*` to dereference, use the `&` to access the memory address.

But in my example below, the same syntax is used to set the address of a `char` and to save a string to the same variable. How does this work? I think I'm just generally confused and maybe I'm overthinking it.

```
int main()
{
    char *myCharPointer;
    char charMemoryHolder = 'G';
    myCharPointer = &charMemoryHolder;
    printf("%s\n", myCharPointer);
    myCharPointer = "This is a string.";
    printf("%s\n", myCharPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to understand how "strings" work in C.

"Strings" are stored as an array of characters in memory. Since there is no way of determining how long the string is, a NUL character, `'\0'`, is appended after the string so that we know where it ends.

So for example if you have a string "foo", it may look like this in memory:

```
--------------------------------------------
| 'f' | 'o' | 'o' | '\0' | 'k' | 'b' | 'x' | ...
--------------------------------------------
```

The things after `'\0'` are just stuff that happens to be placed after the string, which may or may not be initialised.

When you assign a "string" to a variable of type `char *`, what happens is that the variable will point to the beginning of the string, so in the above example it will point to `'f'`. (In other words, if you have a string `str`, then `str == &str[0]` is always true.) **When you assign a string to a variable of type `char *`, you are actually assigning the address of the zeroth character of the string to the variable.**

When you pass this variable to `printf()`, it starts at the pointed address, then goes through each char one by one until it sees `'\0'` and stops. For example if we have:

```
char *str = "foo";
```

and you pass it to `printf()`, it will do the following:

1. Dereference `str` (which gives `'f'`)
2. Dereference `(str+1)` (which gives `'o'`)
3. Dereference `(str+2)` (which gives another `'o'`)
4. Dereference `(str+3)` (which gives `'\0'` so the process stops).

This also leads to the conclusion that what you're currently doing is actually *wrong*. In your code you have:

```
char charMemoryHolder = 'G';
myCharPointer = &charMemoryHolder;
printf("%s\n", myCharPointer);
```

When `printf()` sees the `%s` specifier, it goes to address pointed to by `myCharPointer`, in this case it contains `'G'`. It will then try to get next character after `'G'`, which is undefined behaviour. It *might* give you the correct result every now and then (if the next memory location happens to contain `'\0'`), but in general you should never do this.

Answer (score 2):

Several comments

1. Static strings in c are treated as a (char *) to a null terminated
   array of characters. Eg. "ab" would essentially be a char * to a block of memory with `97 98 0`. (97 is 'a', 98 is 'b', and 0 is the null termination.)
2. Your code `myCharPointer = &charMemoryHolder;` followed by `printf("%s\n", myCharPointer)` is *not* safe. printf should be passed a null terminated string, and there's no guarantee that memory contain the value 0 immediately follows your character charMemoryHolder.

Answer (score 0):

In C, string literals evaluate to pointers to read-only arrays of chars (except when used to initialize `char` arrays). This is a special case in the C language and does not generalize to other pointer types. A `char *` variable may hold the address of either a single `char` variable or the start address of an array of characters. In this case the array is a string of characters which has been stored in a static region of memory.

Answer (score 0):

`charMemoryHolder` is a variable that has an address in memory.

`"This is a string."` is a string constant that is stored in memory and also has an address.

Both of these addresses can be stored in `myCharPointer` and dereferenced to access the first character.

In the case of `printf("%s\n", myCharPointer)`, the pointer will be dereferenced and the character displayed, then the pointer is incremented.  It repeasts this until finds a null (value zero) character and stops.

Hopefully you are now wondering what happens when you are pointing to the single `'G'` character, which is not null-terminated like a string constant.  The answer is "undefined behavior" and will most likely print random garbage until it finds a zero value in memory, but could print exactly the correct value, hence "undefined behavior".  Use `%c` to print the single character.